# Filtering array with 1 array condition and external boolean conditions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Filtering `carArray` with a certain conditions from user.

When user checked `red` checkbox, it will filter cars with red paint.
When user checked `green` checkbox, it will filter cars with green paint. When user checked both `red` and `green` checkbox, it will show both red and green cars. (and so on with N user conditions)

I am using 2 check boxes for this example. I have more than 5 check boxes in my real implementation.

I started with `showRed`, `showGreen` boolean vars to track what users wants and an array of `car` object.

```
[ {
       carName: xxx, 
       color: 'red'
  },
  {
       carName: yyy, 
       color: 'green'
  },
   .....
]

filteredCars = carArray.filter((car) => {
    // Problem: I tried to check for showRed and 
    // showGreen before returning but found out that I can 
    // only return once in here
    if (showRed) {
        return car.color === 'red';
    }
    if (showGreen) {
        return car.color === 'green';
    }
});
```

I am currently facing some problems on filtering with multiple user conditions.

Comment: So, even if showRed is true and car.color is not red, you still want to check if car.color could be green?

Answer (score 5):

Why not put the wanted colors in an array `colors` and check against the car color

```
filteredCars = carArray.filter(({ color }) => colors.includes(color));
```

Answer (score 4):

On checkbox change, you should build an array of checked colors. For example, if `red` and `green` are checked, produce an array of `['red', 'green']`. Then, for your filter function, test to see if the car's color is included in that array:

```
// colorsToShow = ['red', 'green']
const filteredCars = carArray.filter(({ color }) => colorsToShow.includes(color));
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess: return exits the calling stack. You should continue iterating and populate a temporary array with the found correct entries, then return the array. That is, do a 'greedy' search.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Jquery

```
let selection = [];


$(".checkBox").each(function() { //you can change .checkBox to your checkBox Id.
    if ($( this ).prop("checked")){
        selection.push( $( this ).text() );
    }
})
```

You can use this snippet.

Then build your filter with this array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can build your filter function using a getter that gets a value from an object (in this case color) and a comparer that will compare that value and return true or false (in this case a function named `hasColor` that is partially applied with a set of colors):

```js
const arr = [ 
  {
    carName: "xxx", 
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    carName: "yyy", 
    color: 'green'
  }
]
//function to get an item from an object (in this case color)
//  defaults to empty string if o or o.tags doesn't exist
const getColor = o => (o&&o.color) || ""; 

//function to compare a value, in this case a string with array of strings
//  in this case the haystack is the colors you are looking for and the needle
//  is the color of the current car
const compareSomePrimitive = (hayStack,needle) =>
  hayStack.includes(needle);
//curryable function to filter, takes 2 functions:
//  getter: to get the value to compare from the object passed into it 
//    like getColor to get color from a car
//  comparer: to compare the value 
const filterFn = getter => comparer => object =>
  comparer(getter(object))
//partially applied filterFn getting the color property from a car
const filterColor = filterFn(getColor);

//partially applied filterFn that has getter and comparer, only need to pass the car to finish
const hasColor = whatColors=>
  filterColor(
    currentColor =>
      compareSomePrimitive(whatColors,currentColor)
  );
//use hasColor filter function
console.log(
  "has color red or green",
  arr.filter(hasColor(["red","green"]))
)

//example with showRed, showGreen
const getColors = settings => {
  var colors = ["red","green"];
  if(!settings.showRed){
    colors = colors.filter(color=>color!=="red");
  }
  if(!settings.showGreen){
    colors = colors.filter(color=>color!=="green");
  }
  return colors;
};

console.log(
  "has color red or green with showRed, showGreen",
  arr.filter(hasColor(
    getColors(
      {showRed:true,showGreen:false}
    )
  ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents on this case is that I would group cars by color so I don't need to filter each car one by one whenever checkboxes are changed.

I would get cars of checked colors from a *map* (where the key is a color and value an array of cars of that color).

In the other hand, I've used [*ramda*](http://ramdajs.com) to avoid boilerplate as it already implements *groupBy*.

```js
const cars = [{
    carName: 'xxx',
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    carName: 'yyy',
    color: 'green'
  }
]

const carMap = R.groupBy(car => car.color, cars)

// A function to get multiple keys of a given map
// (using objects instead of Map). It will get one or 
// more arrays, and that's why I use R.flatten: to get a flat 
// array of cars of different colors
const multiMapGet = (keys, map) => R.flatten(keys.map(key => map[key]))

// The array of colors would be the checked checkbox selected
// colors
const carsOfColors = multiMapGet(['red', 'green'], carMap)

console.log(carsOfColors)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let filteredCars=[];
            let filteredData = carsArray.filter(function(car){
                    if(showRed && car.color === 'red') {
                        filteredCars.push(car);
                    }
                    if(showGreen && car.color === 'green') {
                        filteredCars.push(car);
                    }
                    //any other color or filter that u want to implement can go here
            })
```

The filteredCars will contain the list of cars that are available after applying all the filters.